# Attempting Shell.Execute VBS command to request Admin, from within a CMD script, Works great unless dropped "%1" filenames have DASHES (-) in them

Tags: cmd, vbscript

This trick has been around for a long time. You can use it at the start of your command scripts to ensure they run with admin rights. (Added a "Hello"/pause to test)

```
@ECHO OFF & CD /D "%~dp0" && (IF EXIST "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" DEL "%temp%\getadmin.vbs") && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>NUL 2>NUL || (ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k CD ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %1", "", "runas", 1 > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && EXIT /B)
ECHO HELLO
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Ive been using this for years and am just noticing today that if I use %1 var (a dropped file onto my script, or a passed param) that contains a dash ( - ), that the VBS script throws an error. It seems to be a special char to VBS?

Is there a trick I could use to prevent this or do I need to filter the -'s and remove them from the input %1 var before I let the VBS portion run?

I'm tagging CMD as well because I'm sure I'm not the first to run into this..

UPDATE: This is another way to do it, this way works with dashes, but I do not believe it can be placed on a single line(which I am trying to achieve as well)

```
@ECHO OFF
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\.Admin\shell\runas\command /f /ve /d "cmd /x /d /r SET \"f0=%%2\" & CALL \"%%2\" %%3">nul& SET _= %*
FLTMC>nul|| IF "%f0%" NEQ "%~f0" (CD.>"%temp%\runas.Admin" & start "%~n0" /high "%temp%\runas.Admin" "%~f0" "%_:"=""%" & exit /b) & REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Classes\.Admin\ /f>nul & DEL %temp%\runas.Admin /f /q>nul
ECHO Hello
PAUSE
EXIT
```

And... as crazy as it sounds to WANT to do, i managed to get it working on a single line ;P But it is the strangest thing, I need an extra close paranthesis at the end for this to work? Anyone know why?

```
(REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\.Admin\shell\runas\command /f /ve /d "cmd /x /d /r SET \"f0=%%2\" & CALL \"%%2\" %%3">nul& SET "_= %*") & FLTMC>nul|| IF "%f0%" NEQ "%~f0" (SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & TYPE nul>"%temp%\runas.Admin" & start "%~n0" /high "%temp%\runas.Admin" "%~f0" "%_:"=""%" & exit /b) & REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Classes\.Admin\ /f>nul & DEL %temp%\runas.Admin /f /q>nul & exit /b)
```